# PDFium Component Suite v7.1 for RS 12

Tags: c++builder, pdfium

I installed PDFium 7.1 but I cannot compile the program

After installation bpl file has been added to Packages so Components are visible. Only I have added manually hpp files to folder 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\23.0\hpp\Win32'.

But while compiling the new program, an error occurs: 'Fpdfview' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration.
After pressing the error button, it takes you to the 'PDFium.hpp' file:

```
class PASCALIMPLEMENTETION EPdfError : public System::Sysutilis::Exception
{
  inline __fastcall EPdfError( System::NativeUInt Ident ) : System::Syyutilis::Exception(Ident) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer from Winsoft on how to correct the PDFium.hpp file

*This header file is automatically generated from Delphi source code and sometimes few manual changes are needed.
In this case you can add **#undef NativeUInt** to solve the compiler error:

```
#undef NativeUInt /* !!! add this line !!! */
    
#pragma pack(push,4)
class PASCALIMPLEMENTATION EPdfError : public System::Sysutils::Exception
{
 ...
```

Or you can comment lines in the EPdfError class where the error is reported.*

But now when linking, there is a more serious problem: the inability to open the 'PDFIUM.OBJ' file

> [ilink 32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'PDFIUM.OBJ'